# How to handle Multiple TestCategory under TestCaseFilter

Tags: mstest, vstest.console.exe

I am trying to Call one out of 3 TestCategory in my code

Test Categories are:-

```
[TestCategory("SystemOne"), TestCategory("FunctionalTest"), TestCategory("RegressionTest"), TestCategory("Sanity")
```

The `VSTest` code for calling the Test Category is:

```
"cmd.exe" "/c vstest.console.exe $automationDLL /Settings:$automationRunSetting /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=Sanity /logger:trx"
```

The `VSTest` code works only when `TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=SystemOne` i.e. the first TestCategory. I am unable to Call the Sanity TestCategory i.e. `TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=Sanity` and so on

Comment: You marked this NUnit but you are not using NUnit. ` Testcategory` is not an NUnit attribute but an MsTest one.

Comment: Tag Changed thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Works fine on my machine. Did you read about TestCaseFilter limitations?

> The MSTest adapter in Visual Studio also works in legacy mode (equivalent to running tests with mstest.exe) for compatibility. In legacy mode, it can't take advantage of the TestCaseFilter feature. The adapter can switch to legacy mode when a testsettings file is specified, forcelegacymode is set to true in a runsettings file, or by using attributes such as HostType.

and:

> The /TestCaseFilter command-line option cannot be used with the /Tests command-line option.

Try to run it without `/Settings` options.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Removing Settings did not work. No Conditions are used that would make the adaptor switch to Legacy.

Comment: No idea then. Like I said it works fine on my computer.